# JavaScript "this.a = 2, b = 3" is "b" looked for in parent scopes?

Tags: javascript, syntax, scope

I know that if you exclude the `var` keyword, JS will search parent scopes

However, I see people assigning multiple vars like:

```
var a = 3,
    b = 2;
```

and I'm assuming this type of assignment doesn't look through parent scopes.

Am I correct in assuming this, and would this example behave the same, or check parent scopes:

```
this.a = 3,
    b = 2;
```

Comment: `var` accepts from 1 to ∞ variable names. Object property access is strictly one object and one property. The second example assigns `3` to `this.a` and `2` to `b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're not correct. `this.` has nothing to do with scopes; rather, `this` is an object and `.a` is a property access. This is not a declaration of any kind, it's just an assignment, which is [separated by a comma](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) from another assignment:

```
b = 2
```

and that assignment will search the scope chain as usual.

In contrast, the [multiple variable declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) uses commata to separate names (the initialisers are optional). It's equivalent to

```
var a, b;
a = 3;
b = 2;
```

Comment: good vocab, assignment vs declaration, expression vs statement

Answer (score 2):

The two constructs you posted do *completely* different things.

```
var a = 3,
    b = 2;
```

In the above, the `var` statement allows `,` to specify multiple `var`'s in one. It is equivalent to;

```
var a = 3;
var b = 2;
```

In the second snippet you posted, you are setting the `a` property of `this` to `3`, then (using the comma operator) assigning the variable `b` (which will involve searching the parent scopes to find a declaration of `b`) to `2`.

For more information, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator